# Create and append single column of 1’s, 0’s, and -1’s in csv file based on assessment of several other pre-existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

```
signal_1 signal_2 signal_3 signal_4
      0        0        0        0
      1        1        0       -1
      1        1        0       -1
      1        0       -1       -1
      0        0       -1       -1
```

I have the signal data above in a csv file that I can pull into numpy arrays representing each column using the code below:

```
"Assign all the data from particular columns to a variable."  
signal_1 = np.genfromtxt("%s.csv" % (i), delimiter=',', usecols=(13,), skip_header=1, unpack=True)
signal_2 = np.genfromtxt("%s.csv" % (i), delimiter=',', usecols=(14,), skip_header=1, unpack=True)
signal_3 = np.genfromtxt("%s.csv" % (i), delimiter=',', usecols=(15,), skip_header=1, unpack=True)
signal_4 = np.genfromtxt("%s.csv" % (i), delimiter=',', usecols=(16,), skip_header=1, unpack=True)
```

I want to append a fourth column named ‘Result’ based on the logic as follows:

```
If signal_1 and signal_2 == 1, then result == 1,
elIf signal_3 and signal_4 == -1, then result == -1,
else result == 0
```

Using the code below:

```
"Determine the action to take."  
action_A = np.where(np.all(np.logical_and(signal_1, signal_2) > 0), 1, 0)
action_B = np.where(np.all(np.logical_and(signal_3, signal_4) < 0), -1, 0)

"Append the trading decision to the csv rate files."
file_path = "%s.csv" % (i)
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        
if action_A:
    action_A = np.concatenate([np.zeros(len(df) - action_A.shape[0]), action_A])
    df[result'] = pd.Series(action_A, index=df.index) 
    # parameter index=False removes the index column inserted by index=df.index above. 
    # removing the index ensures the signal calculation is on the same column after each iteration.
    df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
elif action_B:
    action_B = np.concatenate([np.zeros(len(df) - action_B.shape[0]), action_B])
    df[result'] = pd.Series(action_B, index=df.index)   
    df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
else:
    df[result'] = pd.Series(0, index=df.index)   
    df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
```

But I get the table below (wrong one because “result” column is all zeroes):

```
signal_1 signal_2 signal_3 signal_4 result
      0        0        0        0      0
      1        1        0       -1      0
      1        1        0       -1      0
      1        0       -1       -1      0
      0        0       -1       -1      0
```

Instead of the one below (the correct one):

```
signal_1 signal_2 signal_3 signal_4 result
      0        0        0        0      0
      1        1        0       -1      1
      1        1        0       -1      1
      1        0       -1       -1     -1
      0        0       -1       -1     -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

df['result'] = np.select([(df['signal_1'] == 1) & (df['signal_2'] == 1),  (df['signal_3'] == -1) & (df['signal_4'] == -1)], [1, -1])
```

Or, if you don't already have a `df` assembled with all the signal_n series, you can also use:

```
import numpy as np
df['result'] = np.select([signal_1 == 1) & (signal_2 == 1),  (signal_3 == -1) & (signal_4 == -1)], [1, -1])
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   signal_1  signal_2  signal_3  signal_4  result
0         0         0         0         0       0
1         1         1         0        -1       1
2         1         1         0        -1       1
3         1         0        -1        -1      -1
4         0         0        -1        -1      -1
```

Comment: Thank you SeaBean! The first answer worked.